# "Latexify" numbers converted to strings in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have many subplots in my plot and I want a separate title for each one of them. The titles are `V1, V2, ...` etc. Thus, I am simply putting a loop to create them:

```
for val in range(1, 7):
    plt.gca().set_title('V' + str(val))
```

However, I want those `V1, V2` to appear as math expressions. For this, I can replace `'V'` by `r'$V$'` but how do I latex the string that comes from number after that, namely `str(val)`? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r'$V{0}$'.format(val)
```

Handing a number to the `string.format` function uses its string representation, so you don't even need that step.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you! I didn't get which first step you are talking about though.

Comment: You don't have to pass `str(val)` to `format`, you can pass `val` and the string knows what to do with it. (Lots of clever tricks to `format`.)